# HStack returning "VStack" view

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to display images stored in an array which I am providing as a collection to ForEach and giving it a `HStack` view to display the result. But for life of me, can't fathom why `HStack` is returning a "VStack" sort of view?

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Home()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct Home: View {

// 40 = padding horizontal
// 60 = 2 card to right side...
    
   var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - (40 + 60)
   var height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2
    
var books = [
        
        Book(id: 0, image: "p1", offset: 0),
        Book(id: 1, image: "p0", offset: 0),
        Book(id: 2, image: "p3", offset: 0),
        Book(id: 3, image: "p2", offset: 0),
        Book(id: 4, image: "p5", offset: 0),
        Book(id: 5, image: "p4", offset: 0),
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View{
        
        
        
       ForEach(books.reversed()) { book in
                    HStack{
                            Image(book.image)
                              .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: width, height:getheight(index: book.id))
                                .cornerRadius(25)
                                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.5), radius: 5, x: 5)
                    }
                    
                }
           
}
       
    
func getheight(index: Int)->CGFloat{
       
      return height - (index < 3 ? CGFloat(index) * 40 : 80)
    }
    }



struct Book : Identifiable {
    
    var id: Int
    var image : String
    var offset : CGFloat
}
```

I have stripped the code to barebones to highlight the issue and have attached my output screenshot for clarity. Please help.

[image: output].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `HStack` being inside the `ForEach`. You are not aligning every view in an `HStack`, but just each separate view in its own `HStack`. It seems that by default SwiftUI prefers a vertical layout.

Consider this incorrect code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(1 ..< 10) { row in
            HStack {
                Text(String(row))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this correct code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(1 ..< 10) { row in
                Text(String(row))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the results. Left is `HStack` **inside** the `ForEach`, and right is `HStack` **outside** the `ForEach`:

[image: HStack inside ForEach]
[image: HStack outside ForEach]